# How to parse an input string buffer as fread would do with a file buffer?

Tags: python, c, string, buffer

I'm trying to adapt the code below to remove the "fread" function because my argument is not anymore a "FILE *pcm" but a byte string "const char * pcm".

```
int32_t pcm_buffer[inputSamples];

while (fread(pcm_buffer, sizeof(short int), inputSamples, pcm)) {
        bufSize = faacEncEncode(hEncoder, pcm_buffer, inputSamples, data, maxOutputBytes);
        ...
    }
```

Is it possible write with the suitable cast the char * from pcm in the "int32_t pcm_buffer" ?

Thanks by advance

### UPDATE

I'm developing a Python C extension to encode "on-the-fly" some small audio wav records to AAC or MP3 (output is a byte stream). The project is on [Github](https://github.com/samidarko/soundcoder).

The first version is working fine because I give a Python File object in argument:

```
input_file (type: file)
stream = wav_to_aac(input_file) // OK!
```

But I need to pass a File-like such as BytesIO which it's not recognized as a File object by PyArg_ParseTuple:

```
input_file (type: _io.BytesIO)
stream = wav_to_aac(input_file) // KO!
```

So, I'm trying to give directly the byte stream in argument:

```
input_file (type: _io.BytesIO)
stream = wav_to_aac(input_file.read()) // KO!
```

When I was reading the file argument everything was simple but now I would like to read the buffer string.

Comment: You know that `sizeof(short int)` most likely is not the same as `sizeof(int32_t)`? That means only half (typically) the buffer will be filled, but that half will still be treated as `int32_t` values.

Comment: As for your question, what are you trying to accomplish? What is the *real* problem you are trying to solve? Please elaborate more, and preferably show more or your *actual* code.